# Applying custom costfunction in TensorFlow's SKFlow model training

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow, skflow

I'm trying to make a regression model with TensorFlow while using the sklearn implementation so it plays nicely with all the other models I've made.  However I cannot seem to find a way to train the model with a custom score function (cost function or objective function).

Is this simply impossible with skflow?

Thanks loads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of the examples uses `learn.models.logistic_regression`, which is basically a built-in high-level model that returns predictions and losses. For example, `models.logistic_regression` uses `ops.losses_ops.softmax_classifier`, which means you can look into how `ops.losses_ops.softmax_classifier` is implemented and implement your own loss function using perhaps TensorFlow low-level APIs.